# Why does a dictionary comprehension show different values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I want to apply a dictionary comprehension to a title and the difference of the publish date and trending date.

```
def vid(videos):
     diff_date = [(x.trending_date - x.publish_date).days for x in videos]
     dct = {x.title : (x.trending_date - x.publish_date).days for x in videos}

     print(diff_date)
     print(dct)
```

Part of the output of diff_date gives:

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2361, 1, 8, 4, 2, 2, 207, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 28, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 4,....
```

Part of the output of `dct` gives:

```
{'WE WANT TO TALK ABOUT OUR MARRIAGE': 7, 'The Trump Presidency: Last Week Tonight with John Oliver (HBO)': 7, 'Racist Superman | Rudy Mancuso, King Bach & Lele Pons': 8, 'Nickelback Lyrics: Real or Fake?': 7, 'I Dare You: GOING BALD!?': 7, '2 Weeks with iPhone X': 7, 'Roy Moore & Jeff Sessions Cold Open - SNL': 6, '5 Ice Cream Gadgets put to the Test': 7, 'The Greatest Showman | Official Trailer 2 [HD] | 20th Century FOX': 2, 'Why the rise of the robots won’t mean the end of work': 2, "Dion Lewis' 103-Yd Kick Return TD vs. Denver! | Can't-Miss Play | NFL Wk 10 Highlights": 1,......
```

As you can see the value of the `dct` gives a different value than in the output of `diff_date`. What I expected to happen is:

```
{'WE WANT TO TALK ABOUT OUR MARRIAGE': 1, 'The Trump Presidency: Last Week Tonight with John Oliver (HBO)': 1, 'Racist Superman | Rudy Mancuso, King Bach & Lele Pons': 2, 'Nickelback Lyrics: Real or Fake?': 1, 'I Dare You: GOING BALD!?': 2.......
```

I'm not sure why it gives a different value. I expect the value to stay the same right?

*Note the input for the function are objects of a class Video

Comment: Try comparing `dct` to `[(x.name, (x.trending_date - x.publish_date).days) for x in videos]`, and you will be enlightened.

Comment: Do you have duplicate mentions of the same title ? if so , a later key's value will overwrite an earlier one

Answer (score 1):

It is because python dictionaries are not organised by order. I can assure you that they are with the correct value but the order is a little jumbled. You can use this code to fix that problem

```
from collections import OrderedDict 

def vid(videos):
     dct = OrderedDict() 
     diff_date = [(x.trending_date - x.publish_date).days for x in videos]
     for x in videos:
       dct[x.title] = (x.trending_date - x.publish_date).days
     print(diff_date)
     print(dct)
```

This is an order dictionary. It takes more space but keeps things organzed. For more information check out [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordereddict-in-python)